# How to create "god rays"?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, lighting

I would like to create "god rays" effect/lighting on a 3D shape. If I have a `Box`, I would like to have a light source behind it that will create "god rays" around it. Below, is an image I found showing the idea (imagine the window as an opaque box and the rays coming around all sides):

[image]

I tried setting a `PointLight` source, but all lights illuminate "solid" objects, so you can't see the effect around them. My guess would be to fill the area around the shape with some sort of air-like, partially transparent material, that engulfs the shape; and that the light can reflect from.

How would I go about creating "god rays?

Comment: The automatic mandatory downvote is here again...

Comment: You should show what you tried first

Comment: @Rogue I wrote explicitly what I tried. It's extremely simple. Add a box and a PointLight behind it. You won't see the box anyway because the light is hidden. Nothing non-trivial to show.

Comment: JavaFX 8 3D does not natively support [volumetric lighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volumetric_lighting).  Creating your desired effect without native support in the underlying toolkit will likely prove extremely difficult for you or anybody else.

Comment: Nvidia created a presentation on the [maths and algorithms behind this effect](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/gameworks/downloads/papers/NVVL/Fast_Flexible_Physically-Based_Volumetric_Light_Scattering.pdf) and apparently have an open-source library in their Gameworks SDK to demonstrate an implementation (I don't have a link to that).  Note, the Nvidia implementation is not JavaFX based and accessing similar functionality from JavaFX would be difficult.

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks! it looks like a dead end for now. i will try to play a bit with the current option to get some semblance of this effect. i have a couple of ideas for specific use cases i want to try when i get the time.